# Normal basis for some cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Google was rather dry on this subject (for characteristic zero). Is this rather obvious but laborious? Can an algorithm look like, say  compute the roots (solvability seems of little help, even on a simple example), find explicitely the automorphisms (how?), then calculate the determinant $\det[g_ig_j(\alpha)]_{(i,j)}$ of the linear system for various numbers $\alpha$ (themsleves linear combination of a power basis of the generators of the spitting field, so solvability could help), check that this element generates an extension of the same degree (linear combinations of the power basis must randomly be acceptable), and then prove that this extension is the same, which may seem excessively difficult for lots of cases.

A first example supposed to be an easy case: $P=T^3 -3T+1$, with only real roots with cyclic group $A_3$ of order 3. SAGE finds $g:x\mapsto x^2-2$ for the cyclic automorphisms generator ([see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160847/polynomials-irreducible-over-mathbbq-but-reducible-over-mathbbf-p-for/160855#160855)). No root $a$ generates a normal basis $a,g(a),g^2(a)$ of the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(a)$. Trying $1+a$, it has $T^3-3T+3$ as minimal polynomial, again with cyclic $A_3$ Galois group, with again the generator $:g:\mapsto x^2-x$ (SAGE), and $det([g_ig_j(1+a)])=-27$, so since $\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}(1+a)$, then $1+a,g(1+a),g^2(1+a)$ is a normal basis of $L$.

For $T^3-2$, it's group is $S_3=D_3$. The roots are known with two generators, $\omega=\frac12(-1+\sqrt{-3})$ and $\beta=\sqrt[3]{2}$. The group is known with two generators:  $\sigma:(\omega,\beta)\mapsto (\omega,\omega\beta)$ and $\tau:(\omega,\beta)\mapsto (\omega^2,\beta)$ with $\tau^2=\sigma^3=\tau\sigma\tau\sigma=id$. Trying numbers  $c=\delta_0+\delta_1\beta+\delta_2\beta^2+\delta_3\omega+\delta_4\omega\beta+\delta_5\omega\beta^2$ with $\delta_i=0,1$, one finds for example that  $c=(\beta^2 + 1)\zeta +  \beta$ has $\det[g_ig_j(c)]\neq 0$. It's degree is $6$ with minimal $P_{\min}=T^6 + 3T^5 + 12T^4 + 25T^3 + 60T^2 + 51T + 127$ (SAGE). It is reducible modulo every prime, because [$D_3$ contains no $6$-cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160847/polynomials-irreducible-over-mathbbq-but-reducible-over-mathbbf-p-for/160855#160855)

The only "easy" examples come with $\mathbb{Q}(2\cos(2\pi/p))$, with cyclic Galois group of order $(p-1)/2$ since $2\cos(2\pi/p)$ seems to generate a normal base. This is not a proof since SAGE calculated the determinants. I mention this because surprisingly (for me), this determinant isn't an integer when $(p-1)$ is divisible by $4$ (at least for primes between $5$ and $50$).

Comment: well if the first coefficient of the minimal polynomial is $0$ then the sum of the conjugates is $0$ and so they can't be linearly independant over $\Bbb Q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over $\Bbb Q$ "almost all" elements in a Galois extension are normal bases.
So taking a "random" element is almost certain to give one. That's because non-normal bases form a proper subvariety of $K$ (considered as affine space over $\Bbb Q$). Alas I don't know any general shortcuts to rigorously prove that an element is a normal basis.

But $2\cos(2\pi/p)$  ($p$ prime) is a normal basis over the field it generates.
This is an example of a general principle. Let $M/L/K$ be a tower of Galois extensions. If $a$ is a normal basis of $M/K$ then the trace $\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(a)$
is a normal basis of $L/K$. The proof is straightforward. Here take $a=\exp(2\pi i/p)$ which is certainly a normal basis of the $p$-th cyclotomic extension. No idea why you're getting non-integer determinants though!

Comment: Here is an example I think with p=5. Let $\zeta=\exp(i2\pi/5)$, $M=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ so $\zeta,\zeta^{2},\zeta^{3},\zeta^{4}$ is a normal basis. Let $c=\zeta+1/\zeta=2\cos(2\pi/5)$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(c)$ so we have the tower of Galois extensions $M/L/\mathbb{Q}$. The minimal minimal of c over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $T^{2}+T-1=(T-c)(T+c+1)$ so the orbit of c is $\{c,-c-1\}$ and the Galois group of $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is $\left\{ c\mapsto c,c\mapsto-c-1\right\}$. Then c is a normal basis and  $\det[g_{i}g_{j}(c)]$ isn't an integer.$$\det\begin{pmatrix}c & -c-1\\
-c-1 & c
\end{pmatrix}=-2c-1$$

Answer (score 0):

1) I tried to write down a proof of the above result. Let $M/L/K$ be Galois extensions, and the Galois groups $G=\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ and $H=\mathrm{Gal}(M/L)$. Then $L=M^H$ and $H$ is normal in $G$ and the quotient $G/H$ is the Galois group of the Galois extension $M/L$. Let $G/H=\{\sigma_1H,\dots,\sigma_mH\}$ for $\sigma_i\in G$. Let $a$ generate a $K$-normal basis for $M$, then the sum $s=\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(a)=\sum_{h_i\in H}h_i(a)$ is an element of $M^H=L$. To show that $s$ generates a normal $k$-basis of $L$, we take a $k$-linear dependance relation $0=\sum_i b_i\sigma_i(s)$ so $$0=\sum_i b_i\sigma_i(\sum_j h_j(a))=\sum_i\sum_j b_i(\sigma_ih_j)(a)=\sum_{g\in G}b_g g(a)$$ since the double sum collects all $G$, so $b_g=0$ since $a$ generates a normal basis. Hence $s$ generates a normal $K$-basis of $L$.

2) Application. Following you, $c=2\cos(2\pi/p)$ generates a normal basis. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and consider $M=K(\zeta)$ with $\zeta=\exp(i2\pi/p)$. Then $\{\zeta,\zeta^2,\dots,\zeta^{p-1}\}$ is a normal $K$-basis of $M$: if $a_1\zeta+\cdots+a_{p-1}\zeta^{p-1}=0$ implies $a_1+a_2\zeta+\cdots+a_{p-1}\zeta^{p-2}=0$ so $a_i=0$ since $1,\zeta,\dots,\zeta^{p-2}$ is a power basis of $M$. Then consider $c=\zeta+1/\zeta \in \mathbb{R}$, so $L=K(c)$ is a real subfield of $M\subset \mathbb{C}$ so $M/L$ is Galois. The minimal of $\zeta$ over $L$ is $T^2-cT+1=(T-\zeta)(T-1/\zeta)$ so the Galois group is $H=G(M/L)=\{x\mapsto x,x\mapsto 1/x\}$. Since $G=\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ is a cyclic group, thus abelian, thus $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $L=M^H$, so the extension $L/K$ is Galois by the correspondance. Hence we can use the result above: $\mathrm{Tr}_{M/L}(\zeta)=\zeta+1/\zeta=c=2\cos(2\pi/p)$ generates a normal $K$-basis of $L$.

Write $p$ as $2q+1$, so $p\equiv 1\mod 4$ when $q$ is even, and $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ otherwise. The discriminant of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p$ is [$\prod_{i<j}(\zeta^i-\zeta^j)^2=(-1)^{p(p-1)/2}p^{p-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240651/the-discriminant-of-the-cyclotomic-phi-px) $>0$, so $\sqrt{p}$ generates a subfield $F=K(\sqrt{p})\subset L=K(c)$ when $p\equiv 1$ and we have a tower $L/F/K$ of Galois fields of degrees $(p-1)/4$ et $2$. Then by the same result, since $L/F/K$ is a Galois tower, $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/F}(c)=r+s\sqrt{p}\in F$ generates a $K$-normal basis $\{r\pm s\sqrt{p}\}$ for $F$.

3) I was initially interested in the determinant of the matrice $[g_ig_j(c)]$ (where $g_i\in G(L/K)$). This matrice checks if $c$ generates a normal basis. I wanted to understand why it is not an integer in case when $p\equiv 1\mod 4$. The final result seems to be that $\det[g_ig_j(c)]=-\sqrt{p}^{p-3}$

Once the automorphisms of $G(L/K)$ are determined (in the example for $p=13$ below), one computes the permutations of the orbit of $c$ under $G(L/K)$, then obtain the symmetric matrix $M(c)=[g_ig_j(c)]$. For the case $p=13$ for example, one obtains: $$M(c)=\begin{pmatrix}c_{1} & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 & c_6\\ c_2 & c_4 & c_6 & c_5 & c_3 & c_1\\ c_3 & c_6 & c_4 & c_1 & c_2 & c_5\\ c_4 & c_5 & c_1 & c_3 & c_6 & c_2\\ c_5 & c_3 & c_2 & c_6 & c_1 & c_4\\ c_6 & c_1 & c_5 & c_2 & c_4 & c_3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{array}{c} () &\sigma^6 &(+)\\ (124536) &\sigma &(-)\\ (134)(265) &\sigma^4 &(+)\\ (143)(256) &\sigma^2 &(+)\\ (15)(23)(46) &\sigma^3 &(-)\\ (163542) &\sigma^5 &(-) \end{array}$$ and these permutations form a cyclic subgroup of $S_6$ of order $6$. We compute the matrix $D=M\cdot M^t$. It has the form: $$M\cdot M^t=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr} p-2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & p-2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & -2 & p-2 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & -2 & -2 & p-2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & p-2 & -2 \\ -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 & p-2 \end{array}\right)$$
The diagonal is formed by the sums (with $q=(p-1)/2)$): $$d_{i,i}=\sum_{k=1}^qc_k^2=\sum_{k=1}^q(\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k})^2=2q-\frac{\zeta}{1+\zeta}-\frac{1}{1+\zeta}=p-2$$

The cyclic permutation $\sigma$ acts on the orbits (and rows): note  $k(i)$ the power of $\sigma$ for the $i$th row of $D$, given by $k:(1,2,3,4,5,6)\to (6,1,4,2,3,5)$ as seen above.

The non-diagonal terms are: $$d_{i,j}=\sum_{r=1}^q c_{\sigma^{k(i)}(r)}c_{\sigma^{k(j)}(r)}=2\sum_{r=1}^q c_{\sigma^{k(i)}(r)+\sigma^{k(j)}(r)} +\sum_1^q c_{\sigma^{k(i)}(r)-\sigma^{k(j)}(r)}$$ with $2\cos a\cos b=\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)$. Since we permute all this $i$'s, we have:

$$d_{i,j}=2\sum_1^q c_i=2\sum_1^q (\zeta^i+\zeta^{-i})=-2$$

Then one computes (via SAGE) the determinant  $\det M\cdot M^t=-p^{p-3}$ so $\det M=-\sqrt{p}^{p-3}$.

I found it rather laborious to determine the automorphisms of $G(L/K)$ and didn't found a smarter route that the following.

For $p\equiv 1$, we have the tower of Galois (real) fields: $$\mathbb{Q}=K\subset K(\sqrt{p})=F\subset F(c)=L\subset M=K(\zeta)\subset \mathbb{C}$$ of respective degrees $2/\frac{p-1}4/2$.

One can compute the minimal of $c=2\cos(2\pi/p)$ over different subfields of it's splitting field $L=F(c)$ and check what the automorphisms do to the generators $\sqrt{p}$ and $c=2\cos(2\pi/p)$ of $L$. For the case $p=13$, the only subfield is $F=K(\sqrt{p})$ since $[F:K]=6$. namely over $F$.

For $p=13$, the minimal polynomial of $c=2\cos(2\pi/13)$ over $K$ is calculated from $\Phi_{13}$ with the change of variables $Z=X+1/X$, which is: $$P_{\min,c}=T^6 + T^5 - 5T^4 - 4T^3 + 6T^2 + 3T - 1\in K[T]\;(1)$$ $$P_{\min,c}=\prod_{g\in G(L/K)} (T-g(2\cos(2\pi /p))=\prod_{k=1}^{k=\frac{p-1}{2}} (T-2\cos(2\pi k/p)\in L[T]$$ and over the Galois subextension $F$, with $m=(p-1)/4$ and $\tau:\sqrt{p}\mapsto -\sqrt{p}\in G(L/K)$ $$P_{\min,c}=(T^m+a_1(\sqrt{p})T^{m-1}+\cdots+a_m)(T^m+\tau(a_1)T^{m-1}+\cdots+\tau(a_m))\in F[T]$$ $$P_{\min,c}=\left(T^3+(a_1+b_1\sqrt{p})T^2+(a_2+b_2\sqrt{p})T+a_3+b_3\sqrt{p}\right)$$ $$\times \left(T^3+(a_1-b_1\sqrt{p})T^2+(a_2-b_2\sqrt{p})T+a_3-b_3\sqrt{p}\right)$$

so expanding and solving the constants of this last equation with $(1)$ gives a solution $a_1=b_1=-\frac 12$, $a_2=-1,b_2=0$ and $a_3=-\frac 32, b_3=-\frac 12$ so $P_{\min,c}$ factors as $P_1P_2$ over $F$ as: $$P_{\min,c}=\left(T^3+\frac 12(1-\sqrt{p})T^2-T-\frac 12(3-\sqrt{p})\right)\times \left(T^3+\frac 12(1+\sqrt{p})T^2-T-\frac 12(3+\sqrt{p})\right)$$
Each irreducible factor has a cyclic Galois group of order $3$, and the calculated discriminant, $p$, a square in $F$, confirms this. Each factor corresponds to the automorphisms sending respectively $\sqrt{p}$ to $-\sqrt{p}$ and to $\sqrt{p}$.

The automorphisms of $G(L/K)$ are given by sending $c=2\cos(2\pi /13)$ to $c_k=2\cos(2\pi k/p)$ for $k\in [1,\dots ,(p-1)/2]$, and $\sqrt{p}\mapsto \pm \sqrt{p}$. We need to compute them explicitely. The Chebyshev polynomials give relations $\cos nx=T_n(\cos x)$ and, since each $c_i$ is a root of a cubic factor $P_i$, this will give quadratic polynomials in $c$ and linear in $\sqrt{p}$.

For example, $2\cos3x=2T_3(\cos x)=(2\cos x)^{3}-3(2\cos x)$. Since $P_1(c)=0$, then $c^3=\frac 12(-1+\sqrt{p})c^2+c+\frac 12(3-\sqrt{p})$, so these relations together gives the automorphism sending $$c\mapsto c_3=2\cos(6\pi /13)=\frac12(\sqrt{p}-1)c^2 - 2c +\frac12(3-\sqrt{p})$$

In the same way, $c_{4}=2T_4(c)=c_{1}^{4}-4c_{1}^{2}+2$ gives $$c\mapsto c_4=2\cos(8\pi/13)=\frac12(1-\sqrt{p})c^2 + c + \sqrt{p} - 2$$

We check that $(T-c)(T-c_3)(T-c_4)$ is the factor $P_1$ of $P_{\min ,c}$ over $F$.

We have $2\cos 2x=2T_2(\cos x)=(2\cos x)^2 -2$ so we have an automorphism sending $$c=2\cos(2\pi /13)\mapsto c_2=2\cos(4\pi /13)=c^2-2$$

The other automorphisms are:

$$c\mapsto c_5=2\cos(10\pi/13)=-2c^2 + \frac 12(1+\sqrt{p})c +\frac12(5-\sqrt{p})$$

$$c\mapsto c_6=2\cos(12\pi/13)=c^2 -\frac 12 (1+\sqrt{p})c - 1$$

and $(T-c_2)(T-c_5)(T-c_6)$ give the factor $P_2$.

Now we can compute the $[g_ig_j(c)]$ matrix. Since $G(L/K)$ is abelian, the matrix $M(c)=[g_ig_j(c)]$ with $g_i\in G(L/K)$ is symmetric. It's determinant is the product of the eigenvalues of it's characteristic polynomial, so one computes $\det(T\cdot I-M(c))$.

$$\det(T\cdot I_6-M(c))=T^6 + (-\sqrt{13} + 1)T^5 + (-\sqrt{13} - 26)T^4 + (26\sqrt{13} - 26)T^3 + (26\sqrt{13} + 169)T^2 + (-169\sqrt{13} + 169)T - 169\sqrt{13}$$ The constant term $-169\sqrt{13}=-\sqrt{13}^{5}$ is the product of the eigenvalues, so is determinant of $M$. We can further factor this polynomial as $$=(T + 1) (T + \sqrt{p})^2 (T - \sqrt{p})^3$$ which shows the eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{p}$ and $-1$ with multiplicites, so again $\det M(c)=-\sqrt{13}^5\in F$.

The case $p=5$ gives $\det M=-\sqrt{5}$.