# How to compute the different ideal of the cyclotomic field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ be the cyclotomic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ by adding a $p$-th root of unity.

There is a notation called [different ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal), which is defined to measure the (possible) lack of duality in the ring of integers.
I want to know what is the different ideal of the cyclotomic field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Fields have no nontrivial ideals. Do you mean the (fractional) ideals of the ring of integers? I can't remember the standard lingo in number theory.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok, thanks for your reminding!

Comment: @pancini this abuse of terminology is very common in algebraic number theory.

Comment: @LukasHeger I suspected that; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's well-known that $p$ is totally ramified in $K$ and that it is the only ramified prime in this extension. The unique prime ideal above $p$ is $(1-\zeta_p)$, so we only need to figure out the exponent of $(1-\zeta_p)$.

The norm of the different is the (absolute value of) discriminant. The discriminant in this case is also [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240651/the-discriminant-of-the-cyclotomic-phi-px):

We have $|\Delta_{K/\Bbb Q}|=p^{p-2}$.

Now if $\mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb Q}=(1-\zeta_p)^m$, then using $N((1-\zeta_p))=p$ we get

$p^{p-2}=|\Delta_{K/\Bbb Q}|=N(\mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb Q})=p^m$

So the exponent $m$ is $p-2$ and we have $\mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb Q}=(1-\zeta_p)^{p-2}$.

Another approach: If the ring of a number field is $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ with $\alpha$ having minimal polynomial $f$, then the different is generated by $f'(\alpha)$. Here $\alpha=\zeta_p$, $f=\Phi_p$.

We have $(X-1)\Phi_p(X)=X^p-1$. Differentiating yields.

$$(X-1)\Phi'_p(X)+\Phi_p(X)=pX^{p-1}$$
Plugging in $\zeta_p$ gives

$$(\zeta_p-1)\Phi'_p(\zeta_p)=p\zeta_p^{p-1}$$

The factor $\zeta_p^{p-1}$ doesn't bother us, being a unit. We know that $(\zeta_p-1)^{p-1}=(p)$ (as, again, $p$ is totally ramified and $(\zeta_p-1)$ is the unique prime ideal above it)
Thus we get an equality of ideals:

$(\zeta_p-1)(\Phi'_p(\zeta_p))=(p)=(\zeta_p-1)^{p-1}$. Which yields the result upon diving by $(\zeta_p-1)$.

Third method (This one is quite a bit more advanced):

Consider the extension of local fields $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_p)/\Bbb Q_p$. Because $p$ is totally ramified in $K/\Bbb Q$, the problem is purely local.

Generally if $E/F$ is an extension of non-archimedean local fields, then the different $\mathfrak{d}_{E/F}$ is some power of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_E$ of the valuation ring $\mathcal O_E$ of $E$. If $E/F$ is Galois with Galois group $G$, then the exponent of $\mathfrak{d}_{E/F}$ may be expressed in terms of higher ramification groups. Namely, we have $\mathfrak{d}_{E/F}=\mathfrak{m}_E^w$, where $w$ is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty(|G_i|-1)$.

Now the higher ramification groups of the field $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^k})=:E_k$ may be computed as $G_i=\operatorname{Gal}(E_k/E_e)$, where $e$ is chosen such that $p^{e-1}\leq i <p^e$. For a proof, see e.g. Serre *Local Fields*. In our situation $k=1$. And so we get a really simply ramification filtration:

$G_{-1}=G_0=\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_p)/\Bbb Q_p)\cong (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ and $G_i={1}$ for $i \geq 1$.

Thus the formula simply yields as an exponent $|G_0|-1=p-2$.